# separation of rows with zero on its 1st column in matlab

Tags: matlab

how can separate my matrix like this
A=[0 1 1 4; 1 2 0 8; 0 3 0 5; 2 3 0 4; 2 4 0 3; 3 4 0 2]
my reference is the 1st column. that if the number in the first column is zero i will segregate it like this:
B=[0 1 1 4; 0 3 0 5]
and C=[1 2 0 8; 2 3 0 4; 2 4 0 3; 3 4 0 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can codegolf this but essentially the machinery would be around this type of indexing with a conditional.

```
>> A=[0 1 1 4; 1 2 0 8; 0 3 0 5; 2 3 0 4; 2 4 0 3; 3 4 0 2];
>> bool = A(:,1)==0;
>> ind = 1:size(A,1);
>> B = A(ind(bool),:);
>> C = A(ind(~bool),:);
>> B

B =

     0     1     1     4
     0     3     0     5

>> C

C =

     1     2     0     8
     2     3     0     4
     2     4     0     3
     3     4     0     2

>>
```